# Access gunicorn flask server without specifying port name

Tags: python, nginx, networking, flask, gunicorn

I have a small mini blog flask application. I execute this application like this:

> $ gunicorn gunluk:app -p gunluk.pid -b 0.0.0.0:8000

I may access it like this:

http://programlama.tk:8000/

But what I'd like to do is access site without specifying port name:

http://programlama.tk

List of the current ip tables rules:

> $ sudo iptables -nvL

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   62  7092 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8000
  593 67706 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8080
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5000
 3631 3641K ACCEPT     all  --  enp1s0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8000

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  655 74798 ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 2790  322K ACCEPT     all  --  *      enp1s0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Also port forwarding settings in the router interface are as follows:

```
Interface  Protocol    Input Port  Output Port    Server IP Adress  Name    Status
nas_8_35     TCP       5000-5000    5000-5000   192.168.1.2     5000    Active
nas_8_35     TCP       8080-8080    8080-8080   192.168.1.2     web2    Active
nas_8_35    TCP/UDP    8000-8000    8000-8000   192.169.1.2     8000    Active
nas_8_35    TCP/UDP      80-80        80-80     192.168.1.2     http    Active
```

I don't have a static ip, I use a free dynamic dns service with a dynamic ip address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a `nginx` thing to handle.

```
server {
listen 80;  # listen onport 80
server_name server_domain_or_IP; #requests to this domain or ip

location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:<fullpath-to-your-project>.sock;
   }
}
```

this is reversing all traffic for `server_name:80` to your app's `url:port`

and you can create a `daemon` for your `Gunicorn` to automatically run on system restarts.

Comment: I made the requested changes. Make a symbolic link `sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/programlama /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` test nginx `$ sudo nginx -t` and restart nginx service `$ sudo service nginx restart` . I stopped gunicorn and this time executed like this `gunicorn gunluk:app -p gunluk.pid --bind unix:test.sock -b 0.0.0.0:8000 -w 4` Still I may access site only specifying port number.

Comment: is your test,sock being created? did your path correctly point to this file? what error do you get without specifying the port?

Comment: I may access now thanks. It seems this was because of my browser's cache.